# Are all images in ImageNet in the leaves?

Tags: dataset, image-classification

If I understand it correctly, then the labels of [ImageNet](http://image-net.org/) are based on WordNet:

> ImageNet is an image dataset organized according to the WordNet hierarchy. Each meaningful concept in WordNet, possibly described by multiple words or word phrases, is called a "synonym set" or "synset". There are more than 100,000 synsets in WordNet, majority of them are nouns (80,000+). In ImageNet, we aim to provide on average 1000 images to illustrate each synset. Images of each concept are quality-controlled and human-annotated. In its completion, we hope ImageNet will offer tens of millions of cleanly sorted images for most of the concepts in the WordNet hierarchy.

Source: http://image-net.org/about-overview

The text above states already that WordNet defines a hierarchy. You can see that by using the Python [`nltk` package](http://www.nltk.org/):

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
nltk.download()
def get_hyponyms(synset):
    hyponyms = set()
    for hyponym in synset.hyponyms():
        hyponyms |= set(get_hyponyms(hyponym))
    return hyponyms | set(synset.hyponyms())
dog = wordnet.synset('dog.n.01')
print(get_hyponyms(dog))
harrier = wordnet.synset('harrier.n.02')
print(get_hyponyms(harrier))
```

(thanks to [Stephan Ds answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33662890/562769))

gives

> set([Synset('harrier.n.02'), Synset('water_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('standard_poodle.n.01'), Synset('dandie_dinmont.n.01'), Synset('courser.n.03'), Synset('wirehair.n.01'), Synset('toy_manchester.n.01'), Synset('puppy.n.01'), Synset('briard.n.01'), Synset('beagle.n.01'), Synset('siberian_husky.n.01'), Synset('manchester_terrier.n.01'), Synset('bloodhound.n.01'), Synset('gordon_setter.n.01'), Synset('leonberg.n.01'), Synset('king_charles_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('yorkshire_terrier.n.01'), Synset('sealyham_terrier.n.01'), Synset('american_water_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('skye_terrier.n.01'), Synset('clumber.n.01'), Synset('pembroke.n.01'), Synset('wire-haired_fox_terrier.n.01'), Synset('shih-tzu.n.01'), Synset('newfoundland.n.01'), Synset('retriever.n.01'), Synset('cocker_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('springer_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('american_foxhound.n.01'), Synset('large_poodle.n.01'), Synset('lapdog.n.01'), Synset('bull_mastiff.n.01'), Synset('affenpinscher.n.01'), Synset('irish_water_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('terrier.n.01'), Synset('keeshond.n.01'), Synset('vizsla.n.01'), Synset('dalmatian.n.02'), Synset('bird_dog.n.01'), Synset('irish_terrier.n.01'), Synset('miniature_poodle.n.01'), Synset('dachshund.n.01'), Synset('australian_terrier.n.01'), Synset('blenheim_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('weimaraner.n.01'), Synset('soft-coated_wheaten_terrier.n.01'), Synset('doberman.n.01'), Synset('kelpie.n.02'), Synset('water_dog.n.02'), Synset('feist.n.01'), Synset('attack_dog.n.01'), Synset('french_bulldog.n.01'), Synset('papillon.n.01'), Synset('bedlington_terrier.n.01'), Synset('foxhound.n.01'), Synset('labrador_retriever.n.01'), Synset('great_dane.n.01'), Synset('kerry_blue_terrier.n.01'), Synset('miniature_schnauzer.n.01'), Synset('pariah_dog.n.01'), Synset('border_terrier.n.01'), Synset('staghound.n.01'), Synset('norwegian_elkhound.n.01'), Synset('redbone.n.01'), Synset('pooch.n.01'), Synset('old_english_sheepdog.n.01'), Synset('police_dog.n.01'), Synset('welsh_terrier.n.01'), Synset('spitz.n.01'), Synset('boxer.n.04'), Synset('tibetan_terrier.n.01'), Synset('shetland_sheepdog.n.01'), Synset('boarhound.n.01'), Synset('border_collie.n.01'), Synset('wolfhound.n.01'), Synset('lhasa.n.02'), Synset('scotch_terrier.n.01'), Synset('coondog.n.01'), Synset('giant_schnauzer.n.01'), Synset('japanese_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('german_short-haired_pointer.n.01'), Synset('entlebucher.n.01'), Synset('griffon.n.03'), Synset('griffon.n.02'), Synset('welsh_springer_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('clydesdale_terrier.n.01'), Synset('hound.n.01'), Synset('brittany_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('corgi.n.01'), Synset('pekinese.n.01'), Synset('mastiff.n.01'), Synset('flat-coated_retriever.n.01'), Synset('sennenhunde.n.01'), Synset('schipperke.n.01'), Synset('english_toy_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('ibizan_hound.n.01'), Synset('airedale.n.01'), Synset('cardigan.n.02'), Synset('miniature_pinscher.n.01'), Synset('bluetick.n.01'), Synset('west_highland_white_terrier.n.01'), Synset('seizure-alert_dog.n.01'), Synset('pomeranian.n.01'), Synset('english_foxhound.n.01'), Synset('bernese_mountain_dog.n.01'), Synset('norfolk_terrier.n.01'), Synset('greater_swiss_mountain_dog.n.01'), Synset('collie.n.01'), Synset('chow.n.03'), Synset('pug.n.01'), Synset('scottish_deerhound.n.01'), Synset('groenendael.n.01'), Synset('golden_retriever.n.01'), Synset('schnauzer.n.01'), Synset('irish_setter.n.01'), Synset('german_shepherd.n.01'), Synset('walker_hound.n.01'), Synset('english_setter.n.01'), Synset('english_springer.n.01'), Synset('sporting_dog.n.01'), Synset('afghan_hound.n.01'), Synset('cairn.n.02'), Synset('rhodesian_ridgeback.n.01'), Synset('chesapeake_bay_retriever.n.01'), Synset('irish_wolfhound.n.01'), Synset('fox_terrier.n.01'), Synset('sled_dog.n.01'), Synset('toy_dog.n.01'), Synset('staffordshire_bullterrier.n.01'), Synset('bullterrier.n.01'), Synset('seeing_eye_dog.n.01'), Synset('samoyed.n.03'), Synset('bouvier_des_flandres.n.01'), Synset('otterhound.n.01'), Synset('kuvasz.n.01'), Synset('cur.n.01'), Synset('guide_dog.n.01'), Synset('malinois.n.01'), Synset('malamute.n.01'), Synset('poodle.n.01'), Synset('curly-coated_retriever.n.01'), Synset('toy_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('basset.n.01'), Synset('toy_terrier.n.01'), Synset('tibetan_mastiff.n.01'), Synset('basenji.n.01'), Synset('field_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('mexican_hairless.n.01'), Synset('setter.n.02'), Synset('great_pyrenees.n.01'), Synset('american_staffordshire_terrier.n.01'), Synset('rottweiler.n.01'), Synset('standard_schnauzer.n.01'), Synset('black-and-tan_coonhound.n.01'), Synset('borzoi.n.01'), Synset('bulldog.n.01'), Synset('sausage_dog.n.01'), Synset('sussex_spaniel.n.01'), Synset('spaniel.n.01'), Synset('working_dog.n.01'), Synset('belgian_sheepdog.n.01'), Synset('watchdog.n.02'), Synset('silky_terrier.n.01'), Synset('eskimo_dog.n.01'), Synset('brabancon_griffon.n.01'), Synset('whippet.n.01'), Synset('plott_hound.n.01'), Synset('liver-spotted_dalmatian.n.01'), Synset('coonhound.n.01'), Synset('saluki.n.01'), Synset('toy_poodle.n.01'), Synset('hearing_dog.n.01'), Synset('chihuahua.n.03'), Synset('lakeland_terrier.n.01'), Synset('shepherd_dog.n.01'), Synset('rat_terrier.n.01'), Synset('italian_greyhound.n.01'), Synset('komondor.n.01'), Synset('saint_bernard.n.01'), Synset('norwich_terrier.n.01'), Synset('pointer.n.04'), Synset('appenzeller.n.01'), Synset('maltese_dog.n.01'), Synset('hunting_dog.n.01'), Synset('smooth-haired_fox_terrier.n.01'), Synset('housedog.n.01'), Synset('boston_bull.n.01'), Synset('pinscher.n.01'), Synset('greyhound.n.01')])
>
> set([])

Now my question:

Are all images of ImageNet in the leaves, e.g. `'harrier.n.02'` or are some images only labeled as `'dog.n.01'`?

(Sub-question: ImageNet was labeled by ordinary people (not specialists in the topic, e.g. for dogs not biologists with specialization in dogs or something similar) via Amazon Mechanical Turk, if I remember it correctly. How did the people there know all these different kinds of dogs? I wouldn't know what a borzoi is... so how did they check if the label was correct and specific enough?)

Are the 21841 synsets ([source](http://image-net.org/about-stats)) leaves or also inner nodes?

Are all images in ImageNet in the leaves? How many leaves are there?

Answer (score 3):

1. No, images are present both in the leaves and in the innernodes.
   A more general category like 'dog.n.01' would be a hypernym to a
   more specific category like 'harrier.n.02' (which would be one of
   the hyponyms of dog) but both the synsets would have representative
   images.
2. According to [this article](https://qz.com/1034972/the-data-that-changed-the-direction-of-ai-research-and-possibly-the-world/)

   > Mechanical Turk brought its own slew of hurdles, with much of the work fielded by two of Li’s Ph.D students, Jia Deng and Olga
   >   Russakovsky . For example, how many Turkers needed to look at each
   >   image? Maybe two people could determine that a cat was a cat, but an
   >   image of a miniature husky might require 10 rounds of validation.
   >   What if some Turkers tried to game or cheat the system? Li’s team
   >   ended up creating a batch of statistical models for Turker’s
   >   behaviors to help ensure the dataset only included correct images.

   According to [Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/2014/09/02/what-i-learned-from-competing-against-a-convnet-on-imagenet/), Turkers query on search engines for
   images corresponding to a label like 'harrier' and then give a
   binary 'YES/NO' answer for inclusion of the image in the set. This
   is a noisy process and sacrifices some correctness to scale at that
   level.

   If multiple objects are present, it could be classified with the
   label for a less dominating object in the image since Turkers are
   unaware of other classes in the dataset and hence wouldn't realize
   it if a more accurate label exists in wordnet for the given image.
3. Synsets can be inner nodes or leaves. For example, as of today, the
   'dog' synset contains 1603 images whereas its child synset 'harrier'
   contains 217 images.
4. All images are not in the leaves. They can be under a leaf or an
   inner node. The specific number of leaves can be estimated using
   their [api](http://image-net.org/download-API) for full hyponym (synset of a whole subtree) on all
   the high level categories